# How do I correctly configure Danted?

Tags: ssh, proxy, socks

I have a debian droplet on digital ocean that I'm trying to get danted to work on. I know I have the right username and password and I want to set up a socks5 proxy with auth. `Maxathon` gives me a `130 error` `ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED` when I try to vist a page. When I fiddle with it I will also sometimes get `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` and 110 error's as well.

My config file is:

```
logoutput: syslog stdout /var/log/dante
internal: wfc.help port = 1080
external: 188.226.227.145
method: username
user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: vnc
user.libwrap: vnc
client pass {
    from: 10.0.0.0/8 port 1-65535 to: 0.0.0.0/0
}
```